# Font awesome npm not working (fonts give a 404)

Tags: css, npm, webpack, font-awesome

I have a laravel build. I included fonts via font awesome like this in my scss file.

I have the fonts in my dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.3",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro": "^5.15.3",
```

```
// Font Awesome
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/scss/fontawesome';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/scss/brands';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/scss/light';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/scss/regular';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/scss/solid';
```

But after webpack has complied, it gives 404 on the font files.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this with:

```
mix.copy(
    'node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/webfonts',
    'public/webfonts'
);
```